# Can you use SLF4J with log4j-audit?

Tags: slf4j, log4j-audit

Can you use SLF4J with log4j-audit?
Documentations says Log4j-audit requires Java 8 and Log4j 2.10.0 or greater, but can you used it with SLF4J with Log4j 2 underneat?

If not, can you use log4j-audit alongside SLF4J? I mean call SLF4J logger for debug loggers and Log4j 2 loggers for audit logging?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use SLF4J alongside Log4j-audit. Log4j-audit has its own API that uses the Log4j 2 API. It relies heavily on Log4j's Message support so trying to use it with Logback would probably not work well.